# Alternate name for BackingStoreException

Tags: orm, interface, naming, abstraction

I'm about to undertake the task of abstracting out all SQLExceptions from an ORM's public interfaces with something more generic - that is declaring a generic exception which would in most cases wrap say an SQLException), and I'm wondering about naming.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of BackingStoreException or StorageMediumException, but neither seems amazing to me and its a sweeping and long-lasting change, so I'd like to have a really nice name for it.

So I'm asking for suggestions and opinions.

Sorry if this is highly subjective but I feel strongly that naming conventions in libraries are actually pretty important.

Thanks.

p.s. The ORM in question is SoenEA (https://soenea.htmlweb.com/trac), written in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `DataAccessException` (borrowed from Spring's great [exception hierarchy](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/dao.html) for data access).